# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybind11'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pybind11, fasttext

I tried to install fasttext by the following command:
`python -m pip install -U fasttext`
but it didn't work well.

I faced the error below:

```
Collecting fasttext
  Using cached fasttext-0.9.2.tar.gz (68 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      C:\Users\dorag\user\ドキュメント\仮想環境\64env\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 38, in __init__
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybind11'
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\dorag\user\ドキュメント\仮想環境\64env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\dorag\user\ドキュメント\仮想環境\64env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\dorag\user\ドキュメント\仮想環境\64env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-build-env-de_xqg63\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-build-env-de_xqg63\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-build-env-de_xqg63\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-build-env-de_xqg63\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 72, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 41, in __init__
  RuntimeError: pybind11 install failed.
  [end of output]



note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I'd like to install fasttext

here is the result of feeze comand
PS C:\Users\dorag\user\ドキュメント\仮想環境> python -m pip freeze
annotated-types==0.6.0                                                                                                  attrs==23.1.0                                                                                                           beautifulsoup4==4.12.2                                                                                                  bleach==6.1.0                                                                                                           blis==0.7.11                                                                                                            bs4==0.0.1                                                                                                              cachetools==5.3.2                                                                                                       catalogue==2.0.10                                                                                                       certifi==2023.7.22                                                                                                      chardet==3.0.4                                                                                                          charset-normalizer==3.3.2                                                                                               click==8.1.7                                                                                                            colorama==0.4.6                                                                                                         confection==0.1.3                                                                                                       cymem==2.0.8                                                                                                            DateTime==5.2                                                                                                           decorator==5.1.1                                                                                                        defusedxml==0.7.1                                                                                                       entrypoints==0.4                                                                                                        et-xmlfile==1.1.0                                                                                                       fastjsonschema==2.18.1                                                                                                  filelock==3.13.1                                                                                                        files==1.1.1                                                                                                            fsspec==2023.10.0                                                                                                       gensim==4.3.2                                                                                                           ginza==5.1.3                                                                                                            ginza-transformers==0.4.2                                                                                               huggingface-hub==0.17.3                                                                                                 idna==2.8                                                                                                               ipython-genutils==0.2.0                                                                                                 ja-ginza==5.1.3                                                                                                         ja-ginza-electra==5.1.3                                                                                                 Jinja2==3.1.2                                                                                                           joblib==1.2.0                                                                                                           jupyter_core==5.5.0                                                                                                     jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2                                                                                              langcodes==3.3.0                                                                                                        logzero==1.7.0                                                                                                          MarkupSafe==2.1.3                                                                                                       mecab==0.996.3                                                                                                          mistune==3.0.2                                                                                                          mpmath==1.3.0                                                                                                           murmurhash==1.0.10                                                                                                      nest-asyncio==1.5.8                                                                                                     networkx==3.2.1                                                                                                         numpy==1.25.0                                                                                                           openpyxl==3.1.2                                                                                                         packaging==23.2                                                                                                         pandas==2.1.2                                                                                                           pandocfilters==1.5.0                                                                                                    pathy==0.10.3                                                                                                           pickleshare==0.7.5                                                                                                      plac==1.4.1                                                                                                             platformdirs==4.0.0                                                                                                     portpicker==1.2.0                                                                                                       preshed==3.0.9                                                                                                          prompt-toolkit==1.0.18                                                                                                  pyasn1==0.5.0                                                                                                           pyasn1-modules==0.3.0                                                                                                   pybind11==2.11.1                                                                                                        pydantic==2.4.2                                                                                                         pydantic_core==2.10.1                                                                                                   Pygments==2.16.1                                                                                                        python-dateutil==2.8.2                                                                                                  pytz==2023.3.post1                                                                                                      pywin32==306                                                                                                            PyYAML==6.0.1                                                                                                           pyzmq==25.1.1                                                                                                           referencing==0.30.2                                                                                                     regex==2023.10.3                                                                                                        requests==2.21.0                                                                                                        rpds-py==0.12.0                                                                                                         rsa==4.9                                                                                                                scikit-learn==1.2.2                                                                                                     scipy==1.10.1                                                                                                           simple-mecab==1.2.1                                                                                                     simplegeneric==0.8.1                                                                                                    six==1.12.0                                                                                                             smart-open==6.4.0                                                                                                       soupsieve==2.5                                                                                                          spacy==3.6.1                                                                                                            spacy-alignments==0.9.1                                                                                                 spacy-legacy==3.0.12                                                                                                    spacy-loggers==1.0.5                                                                                                    spacy-transformers==1.1.9                                                                                               srsly==2.4.8                                                                                                            SudachiDict-core==20230927                                                                                              SudachiDict-full==20230927                                                                                              SudachiPy==0.6.7                                                                                                        SudachiTra==0.1.8                                                                                                       sympy==1.12                                                                                                             thinc==8.1.12                                                                                                           threadpoolctl==3.1.0                                                                                                    tinycss2==1.2.1                                                                                                         tokenizers==0.13.3                                                                                                      torch==2.1.0                                                                                                            tornado==4.5.3                                                                                                          tqdm==4.66.1                                                                                                            traitlets==5.13.0                                                                                                       transformers==4.25.1                                                                                                    typer==0.9.0                                                                                                            typing_extensions==4.8.0                                                                                                tzdata==2023.3                                                                                                          urllib3==1.24.3                                                                                                         wasabi==1.1.2                                                                                                           wcwidth==0.2.9                                                                                                          webencodings==0.5.1                                                                                                     zope.interface==6.1

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue with `fasttext` installation.

Run

```
pip install wheel
```

**before installing `fasttext`**

Because `pip 23.1` changed its build behavior when wheel package is not present.

git link: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/512#issuecomment-1718315762

Answer (score 1):

The `fasttext` package at PyPI is the Facebook's own Python wrapper of their non-Python FastText code. But per [their official page](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/python-module.html):

> ### Requirements
>
> fastText builds on modern Mac OS and Linux distributions.

Note: Windows is not mentioned, and your error output implies you're trying to install (and thus build) this code on Windows.

I have occasionally seen reports of people who've succeeded in getting that FastText code to build on Windows, by adding extra compilation tools & options, but not via a simple default `pip install fasttext`. You could conciably search down one of those reports, and perhaps some unofficial (non-PyPI package repository) builds ('wheels') that include everything that'd work on your system. Some alternative things that *might* work:

- (per the [sibling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77630437/130288)) manually installing `wheel` support before `fasttext`: `pip install wheel`; or…
- using one of the unofficial/unsupported pre-built wheels for Windows from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fasttext](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#fasttext); or…
- using the `fasttext-wheel` package from PyPI instead (`pip install fasttext-wheel`) – though I don't believe this comes from Facebook itself, so its reliability/safety would depend on its alternate contributor/maintainers

You could also consider switching to Linux, perhaps in a virtual machine on your Windows system, if you want a straightforward local install of the `fasttext` package. (Some open-source Python data science projects are better-supported & tested on non-Windows systems.)

Another Python option that supports most aspects of the FastText algorithm, including on Windows, is the `FastText` model class in the `gensim` package. (It's missing the `-supervised` mode, & a few other rarely-used options.)

Separately, not as a solution to your problem but as a matter of good practices, you may want to make `pip` installations of such packages into project-specific 'virtual environments' (as are provided by the Python `venv` functionality or popular helper frameworks like `conda`). Then, you're not changing the system's packages (with what you're installing, or any other packages it pulls in as dependencies) in ways that might break other Python utilities or your other Python projects with slightly-different installed-package needs.